# Cannot login for one user, changing password have no effect

Tags: arch-linux, authentication

I have change the user's (user1) password using `root`

```
passwd user1
```

but when i tried to `ssh user@localhost` or through `gdm` or `tty` it always failed

the `journalctl` log shows

```
Failed password for user1 from ::1 
FAILED LOGIN 1 FROM tty3 FOR user1, Authentication failure
pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): conversation failed
pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): auth could not identify password for [user1]
```

I'm using fresh Arch Linux installation (64-bit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the solution was, change the `/etc/passwd` file

for `user1`'s shell from `/usr/bin/bash` into `/bin/bash`

Comment: Just ran into the same problem. Any idea why this is? `/usr/bin/bash` and `/bin/bash` both execute a shell. But only the latter will allow proper login.

Comment: yeah I never found any documentation for this

Comment: Is /usr/bin/bash a symlink to /bin/bash?  It may not work if it's a symlink.

Comment: no.. `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 787584 2014.10.06 13:06 /usr/bin/bash*` it isn't
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 787584 2014.10.06 13:06 /bin/bash*`

Comment: /usr/bin/bash is the same file as /bin/bash, as /bin is a symlink to /usr/bin. you can add /usr/bin/bash to the /etc/shells file and that should work for /usr/bin/bash login, but that's non-standard

Comment: The cause is that pam_shells.so requires a valid shell in /etc/shell. /usr/bin/bash, even if it's a symlink, is not listed in /etc/shells, so the login is denied. To make it easier for others to find, I'll mention that I could log in via ssh pubkey but not with a password. The salient detail here is that sshd *skips PAM altogether* for pubkey logins, so pam_shells.so never runs, even if you have `UsePAM yes`. That option only applies to password / kbdinteractive logins.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is in the file `/etc/shells` as documented in `man 5 shells`.

To cut it short "*[that] is a text file which contains the full pathnames of valid login shells*".

Traditionally `/etc/shells` only contains `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash`.

So, in order to "fix" that issue, you either add `/usr/bin/bash` to `/etc/shells` or change the user's shell to be `/bin/bash` for example by using `chsh`.

Modern distributions have `/bin` as a symlink to `/usr/bin` so the former fix should be the right one. Be warned that this could break a number of programs that *don't* use the `getusershell()` call but have hard-coded shell paths.

The one and only shell you should rely upon is `/bin/sh`, though.

Answer (score 0):

1.**Login as root**
enter username as root, I prefer text(tty# ex: tty2) mode for simplicity. Open it by 
Ctrl + Alt + F#(any of function keys F2-F7)

```
username : root
password :
```

2.**Check for user's shell**

```
$less /etc/passwd
```

you may see some thing like

```
mr_rathod:x:1000:1000:Abhay Raj Singh Rathod:/home/mr_rathod:/usr/bin/bash (unaccessible shell)
mr_rathod:x:1000:1000:Abhay Raj Singh Rathod:/home/mr_rathod:/bin/zsh (unvailable shell)
```

3.**Change the passwd file** fix it by editing passwd file

```
# nano /etc/passwd
```

changing shell to **/bin/bash** would work as it is present in most UNIX based system